# Using codable protocol to parse JSON

Tags: swift

The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format. Trying to parse the JSON given below. Throws error when included the data object also inside the struct

**My JSON**

```
{
    "status": 200,
    "message": "Logged in successfully.",
    "error_message": [],
    "data": {
        "id": "179",
        "home_address": "Optiquall  Pune Maharashtra India",
        "user_login": "mukti.thakor@optiquall.com",
        "first_name": "mukti",
        "last_name": "thakor",
        "email": "mukti.thakor@optiquall.com",
        "phone_number": "",
        "timezone": "Asia/Calcutta",
        "is_google_authenticated": "1",
        "is_facebook_authenticated": "1",
        "image_url": "",
        "active_trip_id": "0",
        "journey_type": "",
        "trip_identifier": "",
        "trip_author": "",
        "token_info": {
            "access_token": "e692f28b8ffe16e683540e7b2d42286a47cbe7fb",
            "expires_in": "3600",
            "token_type": "Bearer",
            "scope": null,
            "refresh_token": "8512b001e35eb69c7d3b45e20138bf91b210bafb"
        }
    },
    "notification_count": 0
}
```

---

**My Code**

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        //decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
        do{

            let succeResponse = try decoder.decode(successResponse.self, from: data!)
            print(succeResponse.data)

        } catch let error as Error{

            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

struct SuccessResponse: Codable {

    var status:Int?
    var message:String?
    var errorMessage:[Int]? = []
    //var developerMessage:String?
    var notificationCount:Int?
    var data:data

    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case status = "status", message = "message", notificationCount = "notification_count", errorMessage = "error_message", data = "data"
    }

}

struct Data: Codable {

    var id:Int?
    var homeAddress:String?
    var userLogin:String?
    var firstName:String?
    var lastName:String?
    var email:String?
    var phoneNumber:String?
    var timezone:String?

    var isGoogleAuthenticated:String?
    var isFacebookAuthenticated:String?
    var imageUrl:String?
    var activeTripId:String?
    var journeyType:String?
    var tripIdentifier:String?
    var tripAuthor:String?

    var tokenInfo:tokenInfo


    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case id = "id", homeAddress = "home_address", userLogin = "user_login", firstName = "first_name", lastName = "last_name", email = "email", phoneNumber = "phone_number", timezone = "timezone", isGoogleAuthenticated = "is_google_authenticated",isFacebookAuthenticated = "is_facebook_authenticated", imageUrl = "image_url", activeTripId = "active_trip_id", journeyType = "journey_type", tripIdentifier = "trip_identifier" , tripAuthor = "trip_author", tokenInfo = "token_info"
    }

}


struct TokenInfo: Codable {

    var accessToken:String?
    var expiresIn:String?
    var tokenType:String?
    var scope:Bool?
    var refreshToken:String?

    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case accessToken = "access_token", expiresIn = "expires_in", tokenType = "token_type", scope = "scope", refreshToken = "refresh_token"
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't do this, `print(error.localizedDescription)`, instead print the error directly like `print(error)`. This will give you a much more informative error message

Comment: When you do you will find out that `id` in your `data` struct should be defined as a String. Some other notes, don't define everything as Optional just out of habit and strunct names should start with an uppercase letter, it helps improve readability if you follow common rules for naming

Comment: Thank you so much, was using an Int where JSON was expecting string

Comment: Types should all be capitalized so that they can be easily differentiated from instances. `struct data:Codable` should be `struct Data:Codable` so that `var data:data` becomes `var data:Data`. Same thing for `TokenInfo`.

Comment: Thanks @JoakimDanielson . Will surely follow the conventions.

Comment: Surely @theMikeSwan

Comment: Side note: I doubt that the value of `error_message` is an array of `Int` and what happens if the login is not successful? @theMikeSwan It's right to name structs with a starting capital letter but you are discouraged from naming a custom struct `Data` which can interfere with the Foundation struct `Data`.

Comment: @vadian the error_message is actually an empty array. But I have to pass some type to it, else it won't compile, so I just passed an int type to it. Not sure whether it is right thing to do...

Comment: The part `message` implies that's an array of `String`

Comment: @vadian actually this is the JSON I get in case of an error-

{
    "status": 422,
    "message": "Unprocessable Entity",
    "error_message": {
        "user_password": "Email or Password is incorrect. Please try again."
    },
    "data": [],
    "developer_message": "Email or Password is incorrect. Please try again.",
    "notification_count": 0
}


How do i parse in case of success  and failure maintaining the same Types

Comment: `error_message` is a `[String:String]` dictionary. This will cause a problem because on success it's an array and on failure it's dictionary. To handle both cases you might write a custom initializer with conditional decoding. The same but vice versa is `data`. I would inform the owner of the service about the issue and ask him to send consistent data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all as mentioned in the comments never `print(error.localizedDescription)` in a `DecodingError` catch block. Always `print(error)` to get this comprehensive error message:

> typeMismatch(Swift.Int, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "data", intValue: nil), CodingKeys(stringValue: "id", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Int but found a string/data instead.", underlyingError: nil))

It tells you that the value for key `id` in the struct `data` (*[CodingKeys(stringValue: "data", intValue: nil), CodingKeys(stringValue: "id", intValue: nil)]*) is a string (*found a **string**/data*) rather than *Expected to decode **Int***.

So declare `id` as `String` as suggested in Sh_Khan's answer.

---

This is a solution to be able to decode both success and failure cases.

The root object is decoded as enum with associated values depending on the value in `status`.

Other changes:

- The structs are named `Response` and `UserData`
- All struct members (except `scope`) are declared as non-optional. If you get an error message change only the affected types to optionals.
- All struct members are declared as constants (`let`).
- To get rid of most of the CodingKeys the `convertFromSnakeCase` strategy is added

**The structs:**

```
enum Response : Decodable {

    case success(Int, Int, String, UserData)
    case failure(Int, Int, String, [String:String])

    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case status = "status", message = "message", notificationCount = "notificationCount", errorMessage = "errorMessage", data = "data"
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        let status = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .status)
        let notificationCount = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .notificationCount)
        let message = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .message)
        if status == 200 {
            let userData = try container.decode(UserData.self, forKey: .data)
            self = .success(status, notificationCount, message, userData)
        } else {
            let errorMessage = try container.decode([String:String].self, forKey: .errorMessage)
            self = .failure(status, notificationCount, message, errorMessage)
        }
    }
}

struct UserData : Decodable {

    let id, homeAddress, userLogin, firstName, lastName, email, phoneNumber, timezone : String
    let isGoogleAuthenticated, isFacebookAuthenticated, imageUrl, activeTripId, journeyType, tripIdentifier, tripAuthor : String
    let tokenInfo : TokenInfo
}

struct TokenInfo : Decodable {
    let accessToken, expiresIn, tokenType, refreshToken : String
    let scope : String?
}
```

---

**The usage:**

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
do {
   let response = try decoder.decode(Response.self, from: data!)
   switch response {
    case let .success(status, notificationCount, message, userData): print(status, notificationCount, message, userData)
    case let .failure(status, notificationCount, message, errorMessage): print(status, notificationCount, message, errorMessage) 
   } 

} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: This is the error I get using above code in case of failure

typeMismatch(Swift.Dictionary<Swift.String, Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "errorMessage", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found an array instead.", underlyingError: nil))

Comment: I tested the code successfully with both cases, the *good* JSON in the question and the *bad* JSON in the comment. `error_message` must be a dictionary in the failure case.

Comment: So sorry in this case i tested on postman and got some another error

{
    "status": 422,
    "message": "Authentcation Failure.",
    "error_message": [
        "The client credentials are invalid",
        "invalid_client"
    ],
    "data": [],
    "developer_message": "The client credentials are invalid",
    "notification_count": 0
}


This will rarely occur as I changed some static key in the post body which is supposed to be fixed for all time

Comment: Works perfectly fine!! Thank you so much! I think I have to talk with my service provider for consistent data

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
var id:Int?
```

with

```
var id:String?
```